# Get data on Facebook user - Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, xcode6

I'm trying to get data on a facebook user by using his ID.
I have an array of facebook user ids called IDs, and I set the graphPath to: "/IDs[0]", when I run the code I get an error.

cam you tell me whats wrong with my code?

```
var pathIs: String = "/"
pathIs += IDs[0]

let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: pathIs, parameters: ["fields": "id, name, birthday, picture.type(small)"])

graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

    if ((error) != nil)
    {
        // Process error
        println("Error: \(error)")
    }
    else
    {
        println("fetched user: \(result)")
    }
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the exact error message please?